# data showing in request payload not in controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm passing information through a JSON string from a text field. It's one answer per question, with multiple customers answering the same question. The problem I am having is that the information is being passed through to the request payload in the network console. however, I am not seeing it in my list in the C# controller class.

[image: request payload]

The following is a debug of the list in the controller, where the SysIntClients list is not flowing through. However it is coming through from the payload in the network response:

[image: Controller class]

My ng-repeat looks as follows:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="question in Question" ng-if="question.SI_ID == '1'">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label class="labelQuestion" id="question_label" for="question_answer">{{question.QID}}: {{question.Question1}}</label>
        </div>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
             <input type="{{question.input_type}}" ng-model="question.SysIntClients.Answer" class="form-control" ng-style="{'height': question.input_type == 'radio' ? '20px' : '40px'}" name="question_answer" id="question_answer" required        {{question.SysIntClients.Answer}}
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

My angular code looks as follows:

```
$scope.SysIntClients =
            [{
                Answer: ''
            }]

            $scope.Question = [{
                QID: '',
                SI_ID: '',
                Question1: '',
                input_type: '',
                SysIntClients: [{
                    Answer: ''
                }]
            }]

 var array = [];
 array = $scope.Question;

                                    alert("Thank you for your input. Now saving data.");
                                    //Save Data
                                    //$scope.sendForm = function (Courier, Customer, Integration, intCapabilities, Retailer) {
                                    $log.log("in the save data function");

                                    $log.log("Form is valid");

                                    //$scope.Courier = Courier; // in order to pass to the reg service in var data
                                    //$scope.Customer = Customer;
                                    //$scope.Integration = Integration;
                                    //$scope.intCapabilities = intCapabilities;
                                    //$scope.Retailer = Retailer;

                                    //var submitData = registrationService.SaveFormData($scope.Courier, $scope.Customer, $scope.Integration, $scope.intCapabilities, $scope.Retailer);

                                    $log.log("in registration service");

                                    //var fac = {};
                                    //fac.SaveFormData = function (Courier, Customer, Integration, intCapabilities, Retailer) {

                                    $log.log("array: " + array);
                                    $log.log("array length: " + array.length);
                                    $log.log("Question: " + $scope.Question);

                                    $log.log("in fac.SaveFormData");

                                    var defer = $q.defer();
                                    var postToAction = $http({
                                        url: '/Home/RegisterUser',
                                        method: 'POST',
                                        data: JSON.stringify({ 'Courier': $scope.Courier, 'Customer': $scope.Customer, 'Station': $scope.Station, 'Integration': $scope.Integration, 'intCapabilities': $scope.intCapabilities, 'Question': array }),
                                        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
                                    });
```

Anyone have an idea as to why my SysIntClient.Answer variables are not pulling through?

Comment: Is `SysIntClients` a property (with a `{get; set; }`)?

Comment: Yes, it does. It's calling SysIntClients from a c# entity framework class called "Question". There is the following line of code: `public Question()
        {
            this.SysIntClients = new HashSet<SysIntClient>();
        } public virtual ICollection<SysIntClient> SysIntClients { get; set; }`

Comment: The request payload suggests that `SysIntClients` is an object (containing a property named `Answer`), not a collection

Comment: I am fairly new to MVC and angular. Is there a fix for that or how I am reading the data?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use angular

Answer (score 0):

MVC would expect that `SysIntClients` be an array on the client-side.  It looks like your setup is correct, from what I can tell?  On the server, MVC gives you access to the raw request that came in so I'd recommend that you inspect the raw data sent to the server and see if something isn't formatted correctly.